# AutoCompleteTextView suggestions clips the textview

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview, clipping

I have implemented a custom Adapter for my `AutoCompleteTextView` along with a custom list item view for the suggestions. Everything works except the suggestions dialog clips the suggestions. This is most likely caused by the fact that the textview is multiline but I can't figure out how to tell the suggestions popup to expand to fill the entire view. Here is my code for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an image to what it looks like:
[image]

**I also noticed that it doesn't clip if the android version is higher, I am testing on 2.3.5 and it clips (my phone) but on 4.1 (emulator) it looks fine.**

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Have a look at the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274243/selection-list-cut-off-in-autocompletetextview-in-dialog

Comment: Is that the same bug though? In that issue it seems the dialog gets hidden behind the main view on his screen. In my situation, the dialog isn't being hidden behind anything, it just doesn't wrap correctly around the content. I didn't mention this above but the dialog has a vertical scroll as well so you can scroll and see the full item.

Comment: Then try setting layout's height to "fil_parent" and then check.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, also tried the text control as well as setting the clipChildren and clipToPadding to false.

Comment: Try change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout.Or just rewrite Adapter and disable reuse of view.