# Scrolling drop-down-menu over the keyboard in autocompletetextview

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I have an Autocompletetextview dropping down the suggestions list, up to the border of the soft-keyboard.

Then, when scrolling over the suggestions list:
  - (in a gingerbread phone) the drop-down-menu automatically increases height covering the keyboard, which is nice since it shows more items.
  - (in an ICS emulator) the drop-down-menu does not increase height over the keyboard.

Is this related to some system property?
Is there a way to force the first behavior also in ICS?

Comment: did you find an answer to this particular issue? I am currently facing the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Strange behavior, faced same problem.

Answer (score 28):

Just add `android:dropDownHeight="100dp"` to the `AutoCompleteTextView` tag in your layout file, it will work.

Comment: I would give you +million if I could... You made my day!

Comment: This is a workaround, given that different devices have different aspect ratios, the 100dp is not a magical number, you need to tweak it to different devices and OS versios.

However, this is the only way of solving it that I've found so far, so I'm upvoting this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Days of searching... Days of agony.. with such a simple fix.  Thank you

Comment: The most direct and stupid solution

Comment: It works, but this is not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain my little trick to avoid that the "drop-down" displays behind the keyboard. The trick is with the dropDownAnchor property.
The solution is set the anchor with a view located on the top of the screen, so the menu will leave from that position, and therefore, will not be covered by the keyboard. For example:

`android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/topview"`

I know that is an ugly solution but this control is too limited.

Comment: Not working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `android:dropDownAnchor="@id/`  to anchor the dropdown to a view.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` to your fragment or activity

Comment: It works <= Android 11
And it doesnt work on Android 12

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that works perfectly with all resolutions is to use the `android:dropDownAnchor` property with a resource ID that references your activity toolbar.

```
<my.app.ContactAutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_textview"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:dropDownAnchor="@id/appbar"
                            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
                            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
                            android:textColorLink="@color/secondary"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things.
First, adjust the soft input mode of that activity in the manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

This ensures views are laid out again when the keyboard is shown. Then, set a global layout listener in your oncreate on the top level view to do the dropdown height calculation when the layout changes. Adjust the dropdown height to be the height of everything below the keyboard, minus some padding if you want.

```
v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                autoCompleteView.setDropDownHeight(view2.getHeight());
}
```

Where view2 is the view/layout that includes everything below the autocompleteview.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions worked. try this

> android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"

or

> android:dropDownHeight="500dp"

If we didn't mention the dropdown height, it would be considered wrap_content. Therefore the item will show behind the soft keyboard.